# Pass variables between widgets flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following widget :

```
class GenesTableTabState extends State<GenesTableTab> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('DataTable of Gene Lists'),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.greenAccent,
      ),
      body: GenesTable(this),
      persistentFooterButtons: [
        RaisedButton(
          onPressed: _onLoadCSV,
          child: Text('Load CSV'),
        ),
        RaisedButton(
          onPressed: _onExportCSV,
          child: Text('Export CSV'),
        ),
        RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Text('Hypergeometric test'),
        ),
        RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).push(
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => VennDiagramWidget()));
          },
          child: Text('Show venn diagram'),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

`GenesTable` is another widget I'm importing from a different file and I need to use one of it's variables inside the `on_pressed` attribute of the venn diagram button (the last `RaisedButton`).

Is there a way to pass a variable from `GenesTable` into this widget?

EDIT:

Also, what changes will I have to make in `GenesTable`?

```
class GenesTable extends StatefulWidget {
  final GenesTableTabState genesTableTabState;

  GenesTable(this.genesTableTabState);

  @override
  _GenesTableState createState() => _GenesTableState();
}

class _GenesTableState extends State<GenesTable> {
  bool sort = false;
  int lastRowIndex = 1;

  List<GenesListObjIndexed> selectedGeneLists = [];
...
..
```

EDIT 2:

`selectedGeneLists` is the variable I wish to pass

And I want to use it in this manner:

```
RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            widget.selectedGeneLists.isEmpty
                ? null
                : Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => VennDiagramWidget()));
          },
```

When I click this button I get `NoSuchMethodError: invalid member on null: 'isEmpty'`

Comment: `widget.selectedGeneLists.isEmpty ` here isEmpty is not in list you can use length property of it

Comment: How can I treat `selectedGeneLists` as a list inside that file? It is defined as a list in the other file @AbhishekGhaskata

Comment: if that is another file then you can pass it through the constructor and the `as` keyword is used to typecast.

Comment: @nvoigt Should the solution work if I want to pass data between two stateful widgets?

Comment: As long as you change the input of the other widget and call `setState` in the callback of the first widget, it should. That's how the flutter widgets do it, that's how they build all those `onValueChange`, `onTap` and `onPressed` methods that you already use.

Answer (score 1):

you can pass it through the constructor like

```
class GenesTableTab extends StatefulWidget {
  final String url;

  const GenesTableTab({Key key, this.url}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _GenesTableTabState createState() => _GenesTableTabState();
}

class _GenesTableTabState extends State<GenesTableTab> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Comment: I am getting an error if these are the only changes I make, please see my edit

Comment: plase see the edited answer @EliranTurgeman

Comment: See second edit

Comment: This is the wrong direction. The OP wants to get data *out*, not pass it *in*.

Comment: Then he should use any state management tech.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can achieve it using constructors like this.

```dart
class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {
  String title;
  SecondPage({this.title}):super(key: key);
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return SecondPageState(this.title);
  }
}
class SecondPageState extends State<SecondPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
    //now you have passing variable
    title: Text(widget.title),
   ),
   ...
  }
```

Then you can pass value using the constructor.

```dart
Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder:(context)=>SecondPage(title:'something')));
```

Comment: I am getting an error if these are the only changes I make, please see my edit

Comment: This is the wrong direction. The OP wants to get data *out*, not pass it *in*.